# DatePickerDialog opens two times

Tags: java, android, datepicker, ontouchlistener

I want to show my date in the Edit-Text with this format: YYYY-MM-DD.
First, when I touch the Edit-Text of the date then the keyboard is still open then Date-Picker-Dialog appears two times. If I set this one time, then again the dialog picker appears. When I set the date the second time, then the date is set in the Edit-Text.
The first Fragment is attached to the first Activity and the second one is attached to the second Activity.

Second Fragment code:

```
package com.example.week9_fragment_task;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;


public class SecondFragment extends Fragment
{
    private Button btnadd,btncancel;
    private Spinner spinner;
    private EditText date;
    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    DBTools dbTools;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        btnadd=(Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btn_add_fragment2);
        btncancel=(Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel_fragment2);
        spinner=(Spinner)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        date=(EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.datepicker);

        ArrayAdapter adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),R.array.health_type,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        date.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Date_Alert(v);
                return false;
            }

            private void Date_Alert(View v)
            {

                DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog=new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)
                    {
                        date.setText(year+"-"+month+"-"+dayOfMonth);
                    }

                    },calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                datePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });
```

Second Fragment XML Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    tools:context=".SecondFragment">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:hint="@string/Hint_Name"
            android:inputType=""
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:autofillHints="" tools:targetApi="o" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/datepicker"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:autofillHints=""
            android:hint="@string/datepicker"
            android:importantForAutofill="no" tools:targetApi="o" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/timepicker"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="time"
            android:hint="@string/timepicker"
            android:autofillHints="" tools:targetApi="o" />
</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    date.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    Date_Alert(v);
                    return true;
                }

                private void Date_Alert(View v)
                {

    getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN
    );                
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        //date_str = dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year;
                        mYear = year;
                        mMonth = monthOfYear;
                        mDay = dayOfMonth;
                        mMonthName = MONTHS[monthOfYear];
                        Log.d("before", "onDateSet: " + mYear + "" + mMonthName + "" + mDay);
                        start_date_str = mDay + " " + mMonthName + " " + mYear;

                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        datePickerDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Keyboard is hide. but the date-picker dialog again appears two time to select the date !!

Comment: i know this is possible ..
but i want to do this task by using (ontouchlistener)

Comment: what device are you using for test.. emulator or physical device?

Comment: Emulator device

Comment: sometimes emulator create problem for touch event as you are clicking on it not touching..may be its the problem of emulator.. you can further test on real device to be sure about it

Comment: please let me know about test

Comment: same problem on physical device

Comment: when i press OK after select the date then another date-picker-dialog is appear

Comment: please try edited one now.. in my case all are performing good

Comment: i am using real device.. I don't trust emulator :p